# Bibtex using different font than document

Tags: fonts, bibliographies

I am writing a LaTeX file currently which is required to be in Times New Roman, so in the prelude I have:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{natbib}
```

The document comes out in the font just fine, but when I go to create the References section via BibTeX,

```
\bibliographystyle{apa-good}
\bibliography{neurons}
```

it appears as though the font is back to the default LaTeX font. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

If it helps, I am using Kile and KBibTeX.

Comment: I cannot duplicate the problem using just those settings. The bibliography was in Times. Could you post a complete minimal working example, as well as a link to the version of apa-good.bst that you're using? (Since it's not on CTAN. I used the version here: http://www.dsg.cs.tcd.ie/~linehane/lyx/apa-good.bst )

Comment: Oh, I should add... while I don't think it's the cause of your problems, consider trying `mathptmx` or `txfonts` packages instead of the (older) `times` package.

Comment: Hmm...I can't seem to get it to do it anymore. Maybe I was mistaken.

Comment: I can't seem to recreate that situation...sorry, I must have been wrong.

Comment: Based on the Hanmyo's comments, I'll close this question